# Merge CSV files with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder of around 200 CSV files. Each only have values in the first row. How do I combine the files so that is each CSV file becomes a row in the new dataset.

For example:

```
1.csv contains:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
2.csv contains:
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]
```

I want to combine the CSV's so that the final CSV looks like:

```
final.csv contains:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

*Each matrix is a row of the .csv, and each , means a new cell.

Thank You!

Comment: Matrix? I don't understand, do your csv's actually contain `"[1, 2, ..` that is, do they actually have those brackets?

Comment: Honestly, you could do this with just `cat`

Answer (score 4):

If you have bash, you can use

```
cat *.csv > combined.csv
```

Or, if you want to do it the python way:

```
import csv

with open('combined.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for fname in os.listdir('.'):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as in_file:
            for row in csv.reader(in_file):
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Here you'll need to navigate to the directory containing your 200 odd csv files.

Answer (score 0):

- **windows cmd** - type copy *.csv combined.csv
- **linux bash** - cat file1.csv file2.csv > combined.csv
- **python** - something like

  ```
  fout=open("out.csv","a")
  for num in range(1,201):
      for line in open("sh"+str(num)+".csv"):
           fout.write(line)    
  fout.close()
  ```